How can I make the grease pencil lines smoother?
My grease pencil lines are really crisp and pixely when they're really close next to each other, especially when I'm scribbling. I understand that this comes from the nature of vectorgraphic lines, but is there a way to smooth them?
Example image: https://imgur.com/a/eX3wiRA

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF
